# Duty cycle of 555 timer

Tags: frequency, 555, duty-cycle

[image]

I am trying to understand the exact working of this circuit, I have been told that this circuit provides a duty cycle of 50% from my previous questions, the same which I successfully verified in LTSpice simulation also, but when I built the exact circuit on a breadboard and observed the waveform on a CRO, I got the following which is clearly not 50%.[image]

I have used the exact same value of components except for R4 which is variable. Can someone tell me what the mistake is as to why I am not able to obtain a 50% duty cycle?
My ultimate objective is note down the corresponding frequencies for different values of R4, but I am confused whether to consider the ON time or OFF time for my application since both are different now?
Apologies if the time scale data of the CRO isn't clear.

Comment: why do you require 50% duty cycle?

Comment: The NE555 will not work well below 5 volts. Use CMOS TLC555 for a range of 2 volts to 15 volts.

Comment: FWIW: This is not a CRO. Also what are the yellow and purple traces measuring?

Comment: @user253751 Purple is probably an RC filter, if yellow is what's driving it. We don't know the heights or DC baseline of that ripple but at least it's not inconsistent with that idea. I'm ignoring the schematic details and only looking at the display, though.

Comment: In one of your previous Questions, you stated that frequency varies when you drive it at 3.3V and know the voltage must be over 4.5V.  How is this behaviour different?  You exceed manufacturers recomendations, you get what you get!  It is that simple!

Comment: The 555 will not maintain a 50% duty cycle as frequency varies, as frequency and duty cycle are very interactive. Pass output through a 74HC74 FF wired as a divide-by-two to get a perfect 50% duty cycle.

Comment: @user253751 The yellow trace is measuring the waveform at the junction of R1 and R5 and the purple trace is measuring the waveform across the capacitor( charging and discharging).

Comment: @VTNCaGNtdDVNalUy  and StainlessStellRat Yes I realized that , I am planning to use an LMC 555 timer now, I think my mistake was that the moment i saw the waveforms of the discharge pin and Capacitor charging and discharging I thought that the NE555 was working even at 3.5V.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers everyone , so am I right in assuming that if I use the same circuit at a voltage greater than 4.5V I would get a 50% duty cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit is theoretically correct, the faults are probably due to the assembly.
(Is R2 likely to be connected to the Discharge pin?) R1 is not required for proper operation at all. The frequency depends on R4 and the duty cycle is always 50%.
[image: 555-50%]

[image: 555-ti]

EDIT:
**NE555 at 3V**. You built it well and measured accurately. :)
The NE555 need a minimum operating voltage of 5V.
[image: ne555at3v]

NE555 at 5V:
[image: ne555-5v]

Comment: OP is using an NE555 on a 3.3 V supply.

Comment: @csabahu Thanks for ur edited answer I understood what the problem is. The issue is I simulated the same circuit in LTSpice at 3.3 V and got a 50% duty cycle, so does this mean that LTSpice is not following the datasheet specifications? Also in ur first graph why is Uout not at the operating voltage i.e 3V but is somewhere around 2.4V

Comment: @Rohit Kumar  The max. output voltage of the [NE555](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe) is less than the supply voltage. Therefore, 1k is required from the output to the supply voltage for a 50% duty cycle. The model in the LTspice system does not appear to be completely correct.

Comment: @csabhau also can u tell me by looking at the circuit i posted in my question how are people saying that it has a 50% duty cycle. I have read the datasheet but didn't understand how it's 50%

Comment: @Rohit Kumar The average voltage of the capacitor is half the supply voltage. Charging and discharging with the same resistance and the equal voltages (+ - VCC / 2) results in exactly 50% duty cycle. The output must swing between 0 and VCC. The output charges and discharges the capacitor.